# get first 3 elements of array then another 3 element then another 3 element in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I have an array of 9 element -
`array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']`.
I have a variable matching the condition.

```
data==='test' ?
        data1 = array.slice(0,3) : 
        data==='test1' ?
        data1 = array.slice(3,6) : 
        data==='test2' ?
        data1 = array.slice(6,9) :
        data1 = data;
```

If data matches to test then data1 should be `['a','b','c']`.
If data matches to test1 then data1 should be `['d','e','f']`.
If data matches to test1 then data1 should be `['g','h','i']`.

I am getting data1 correctly if data is equivalent to test but after not getting correct data in test1 & test2. Getting none in test1 & test2.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: you only assign data once, so it's value will not change, you can either turn this into a function and have a different return value each time, or create a custom getter to the array

Comment: It appears your code already works... when `data === 'test`' then `data1` is set to `['a', 'b', 'c']`, when `data === 'test1`' then `data1` is set to `['d', 'e', 'f']`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Could use a `switch` statement? // for better legibility

```js
const array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
const data = 'test1';
let data1;

switch (data) {
  case 'test':
    data1 = array.slice(0,3);
    break;
  case 'test1':
    data1 = array.slice(3,6);
    break;
  case 'test2':
    data1 = array.slice(6,9);
    break;
  default: 
    data1 = data;
    break;
}
```

Comment: the question is asking about dynamic reference to the array elements without actually calling the ternary operators multiple times

Answer (score 1):

I would use the number behind the `test` string as a multiplier to get the desired part;

```js
const data = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'];

console.log(getDataPart('test'));
console.log(getDataPart('test1'));
console.log(getDataPart('test2'));

function getDataPart(str) {
  
    // Get number behind 'test', fallback to '0'
    const n = (str.length <= 4) ? 0 : str.substring(4);
    
    // Return desired part
    return data.slice((n*3), (n*3) + 3)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the positions inside an object, and get the positions using the data value:

```js
const data = "test1";
const array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
const pos = {
  "test": [0,3], 
  "test1": [3,6], 
  "test2": [6,9]
}
const data1 = array.slice(...pos[data]);
console.log(data1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
const data = 'test2';    

const data1 = data==='test' ? array.slice(0,3) : (data==='test1' ? array.slice(3,6) : 
     (data==='test2' ? array.slice(6,9) : data));
console.log(data1);
```